# What are the ascii value of keyboard arrow keys that can be used in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

In my application, Upon entering the search term, Suggestions are displayed. I have used **click element** to select a suggestion from the list and used enter key(Press Key  ${locator}  \013), but nothing worked for me. I have my script as follows:

```
    Input text  ${search_box}  Chris
    Press Key  ${suggestion_1}  \\013
```

Upon using above script I'm getting the following error **ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element  is not reachable by keyboard**
Hence i have decided to use

```
    Press key  ${search box}  \\040(ascii value of down arrow key)
```

before

```
    Press Key  ${suggestion_1}  \\013
```

When i used 040 for down arrow key "(" is pressed. Kindly help me to handle this. How can i select a suggestion from the list using keyboard actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `\\040` you've given the base-10 value of, 40, which is `(`, thus it typed that.

For the down arrow, [use `\ue015`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.keys.html#selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.ARROW_DOWN), and here's the full list of special characters' codes for selenium:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.keys.html